# rsync filled up dev/nvme0n1p2: how do I reverse this?

Tags: filesystem, rsync

I'm new to looking after a linux computer. I'm runnning Ubuntu 18.04.04 LTS. I wanted to make a backup on an external harddrive using rsync. Unfortunately the name of the hard drive was two words and I forgot to quote them. I ran this:

```
sudo rsync -aAXv --delete --dry-run --exclude=/dev/* --exclude=/proc/* --exclude=/sys/* --exclude=/tmp/* --exclude=/run/* --exclude=/cdrom/* --exclude=/mnt/* --exclude=/media/* --exclude="swapfile" --exclude="lost+found" --exclude=".cache" --exclude="Downloads" --exclude=".VirtualBoxVMs"--exclude=".ecryptfs" / /media/alastair/Seagate Basic
```

This ran until the local disc was full. Nothing was copied to the external drive.

This is the output of df:

```
alastair@alastair-linux:/$ df
Filesystem      1K-blocks      Used  Available Use% Mounted on
udev             16383896         0   16383896   0% /dev
tmpfs             3281660      2076    3279584   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p2  479152840 452003364    2740084 100% /
tmpfs            16408296      1092   16407204   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                5120         4       5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            16408296         0   16408296   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0         167680    167680          0 100% /snap/spotify/41
/dev/loop1          15104     15104          0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/399
/dev/loop3           9344      9344          0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/94
/dev/loop2          56064     56064          0 100% /snap/core18/1668
/dev/loop4         160512    160512          0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/110
/dev/loop5           4480      4480          0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/704
/dev/loop6         178944    178944          0 100% /snap/inkscape/5874
/dev/loop7          15104     15104          0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/495
/dev/loop8         179072    179072          0 100% /snap/skype/118
/dev/loop9          46080     46080          0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1440
/dev/loop10         56320     56320          0 100% /snap/core18/1705
/dev/loop11          9344      9344          0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/95
/dev/loop12         49536     49536          0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1474
/dev/loop13          4352      4352          0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/544
/dev/loop15         93568     93568          0 100% /snap/core/8592
/dev/loop14        144128    144128          0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/92
/dev/loop16          3840      3840          0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/135
/dev/loop17         93568     93568          0 100% /snap/core/8689
/dev/loop18        144128    144128          0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/98
/dev/loop19           256       256          0 100% /snap/gtk2-common-themes/9
/dev/loop20        185472    185472          0 100% /snap/spotify/36
/dev/loop21        164096    164096          0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116
/dev/loop22          3840      3840          0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/127
/dev/loop23          1024      1024          0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/93
/dev/loop24          1024      1024          0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/81
/dev/nvme0n1p1     523248      6152     517096   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs             3281656        16    3281640   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs             3281656        56    3281600   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb1      1953512032    283812 1953228220   1% /media/alastair/Seagate Basic
```

I managed to free up enough memory to run a web browser by deleting a couple of things.

Can someone help me to understand what's going on here?
Can I get back to the state before I ran rsync?
If it copies files to somewhere on my system - where are they? How can I recognise and delete them?

I'm really stuck and a bit afraid of doing somthing else wrong - any help would be very much appreciated!

Alastair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But, the `-v` `rsync` option stands for "verbose"! It told you what it was doing.

Did you really run the rsync command with the

```
-n, --dry-run         perform a trial run with no changes made
```

option? I assume not.

The "`*`" character is special in the Linux shell, often standing for "All Files", so, to avoid unintended expansion, single quote ("`'`") all file patterns containing "`*`", e.g,

```
--exclude='/dev/*' --exclude='/proc/*' --exclude='/sys/*'
```

as shown in `man rsync`.

To illustrate this, replace `sudo` in your command with `echo` to see the expansions.

The space character ("") is also special. It is used to separate parameters, and MUST be quoted whenever it is part of a filename. There are 3 ways of quoting spaces, so your destination should by typed as:

```
/media/alastair/Seagate\ Basic
"/media/alastair/Seagate Basic"
'/media/alastair/Seagate Basic'
```

The *actual* `rsync` command (not the one with `--dry-run`) looks like you're trying to write into `/media/alastair/Seagate`, and, since `/media` is a directory on the root filesystem, you filled up '/'.

Look at it with

```
du -sk /media/alastair/Seagate
ls -l /media/alastair/Seagate
```

and free the space (if you're SURE) by

```
sudo rm -rf /media/alastair/Seagate
```

Comment: Thanks for all the useful comments. You're quite right, the dry run wasn't in the commant I actually ran. The strange thing is, there is no file or directory "media/alastair/Seagate" so I have no idea where everything was written to!

Comment: I've found it - it wrote to a folder called Basic in root. Deleting that freed up the memory.